# PDO object performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I tested today PDO performance like this :

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mw", 'root', '');
$stop = microtime(true);
echo $stop - $start;
```

And the result was pretty surprising (running locally on my Windows 8.1 Laptop)

ELLAPSED : **1.0117259025574**

During a the script execution, I cache the PDO object in a static variable so I don't have to create a new one for another query.
But this caching method only works during the script execution.

My script runs in **1.25 seconds** of which 1.01 are used to create the PDO object.
Is there a way to cache the PDO object for the whole session or for multiple users ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: That's not the type of environment to run a benchmark test on.

Comment: It *could* also be the database that's making the operation slow. There are too many moving parts here to say anything for sure. It is certainly a lot faster in my regular environments.

Comment: Running your code on my 5-year-old Win7 laptop (which was pretty low-spec to start with) returns values like `0.00019407272338867`. Caching the PHP object should not be your starting point here. What sort of times you get for a very simple `for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) { }`?

Comment: What happens when you swap localhost for 127.0.0.1?

Comment: This isnt the right way to test the pdo object. You may have your servers busy with something else as well.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, after a restart of my VM it just worked fine on my test file. I still have the issue with my website, but PDO is not to blame. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested same code on my server and connecting with db Via PDO .

$start time is  1414590258.7735
$end time is    1414590258.7736
And $end time- $start time is 0.0001530647277832

My code is

```
enter code here
 $start = microtime(true);
 new PDO("mysql:host=$mysqlnd_appname1;dbname=$db1",$user1,$pass1);
 $stop = microtime(true);
 echo($start);
 echo "<br />";
 echo $stop;
 echo "<br />";
 echo $stop - $start;
```

So its PDO connection performance is good , its also depend on your sever and how my sql server respond to your php server.
 for more details visit this http://archive.jnrbsn.com/2010/06/mysqli-vs-pdo-benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

If connection overhead is an issue, you can do this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mw", 'root', '', array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php